# Best practices in using URL Rewriter

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have an ASP.NET web application and I'm using the URL Rewriter in IIS. I want to make the URL's simple and meaningful so I created a rule in IIS for every page like this:

- MySite/Admin/AddEditStudent.aspx will be "MySite/Student/New"
- MySite/Admin/AddEditStudent.aspx?ID={Number} will be "MySite/Student/{Number}"
- MySite/Admin/Students.aspx will be "MySite/Students"
- MySite/Admin/AddEditBook.aspx will be "MySite/Book/New"
- MySite/Admin/AddEditBook.aspx?ID={Number} will be "MySite/Book/{Number}"
- MySite/Admin/Books.aspx will be "MySite/Books"
- ....
- ....
- ....
- And so on

I have many pages and I'm afraid I might be using the wrong away lthough the above is working fine. I thought there might be a way to use fewer number of rules in a general way.

My second question is about the home page. Currently it's like this:

- MySite/Public/Home.aspx will be "MySite/Home"

However, I want it to be only "MySite" without needing to add the "/Home" part. Is it possible to do it this way?

Thanks in advance,

PS: "MySite" is a replacement of the localhost which I made in the host file, but when I deploy the application on production it will be the DNS name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First Question

In my idea defining the routes table in code is more easier and flexible. You can define the route in `Application_Start` of `Global.asax`. Also include namespace `System.Web.Routing`.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute",
    "BookStore/{Name}",
    "~/Webpages/BookStore/ViewBookDemo.aspx");
}
```

So your `web.config` will be cleaner and easier to setting other configurations.

### Second Question

First of all set your default document in web.config on your default page as here:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="home.html" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now every links whose href is `'/'` will rewrite your route on default document without showing the `home.html` in the shown url.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Ramin. For the first question, I agree with you that coding is easier, but do I still need to do it for every page or there's a general thing? For the second question, the home page is inside a folder called "Public" not at the root, so if I set default document users will have to request it this way: "MySite/Public" and I want it just "MySite"

Comment: You're welcome bro, My example was general but if I want to give u the exact config, you should set the default document as "MySite/Public/Home.aspx". So your default route will be your domain and works as '/'.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew I could add the full path in default documents